# Singular vectors of sum of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

Presume we have two positive semi-definite matrices $X = UDU^{\top}$ and $X' = U'D'U'^{\top}$. Is there a result on how the singular vectors for the sum $X + X'$ can be expressed in terms of $U$ and $U'$? Or a result on how the singular values can be expressed in terms of the original ones? I thought it must be some kind of "weighting" between the two, but I do not get there.

Comment: this is strongly related to (nowadays proved) Horn's Conjecture, see e.g. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/

Comment: Horn's Conjecture does not tell you anything about eigenvectors, though, only about eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. It turns out I don't need to know anything about the eigenvectors.